# How to create a dynamic page title using PHP

Tags: php, dynamic, title

Hi I was wondering if anyone can help with this PHP problem.

Is it possible to use the text in a H2 tag and use that to populate the page title dynamically.

I'd also like to be able to use this same technique to add the H2 text into the meta description - Can anyone help?

Comment: Where does the text of the H2 originate?  Is it static text in an HTML file?  Do you have control over it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That sounds like something that jQuery would excel at:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery-1.4-min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        document.title = $('h2:first').text();
    });
</script>
```

To modify the meta data, you would do more of the same. I strongly recommend [jQuery - Novice to Ninja](http://www.sitepoint.com/books/jquery1/) as an amazing way to get into great depth with jQuery.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta description="" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('meta:first').attr('description', $('h2:first').text());
        alert($('meta:first').attr('description'));
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Testing 123</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there a way to also add the content of the H2 tag into the meta description too?

Comment: Just tried this and it works a treat. Thanks! Still need to get the same info into the meta description...

Comment: Thank you Jonathan for all your help! :)

Answer (score 5):

If your h2 text is dynamically made then other parts of your web page can be dynamically created too. For example, if you have a variable $a = "My Text"

```
<?php
$a = "My Text"
?>
<html>
<head>
<title><?php echo $a;?></title>
</head>
<body>
<h2><?php echo $a;?></h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Using this technique, you can define the text of other parts of the web page.

Comment: Hi, The H2 tag isn't dynamically created. Is there a way to wrap the H2 tag in some PHP so it spits out a page title and adds the text in the H2 tag into the meta description?

Comment: @Stephen Not exactly.  How many pages would you need to do this on?

Comment: Ah, then one of the best ways to do this is via jQuery. I believe Jonathan answered this in his jQuery answer thread. (+1)

Comment: @George Marian I need to add this code to about 45 pages, by hand! The jQuery technique suggested by @Jonathan works great. But I also need a way to put the same info from the H2 tag into the meta data description.

Comment: @Stephen Ideally, what you'd want is a script to automate that for you and then you'd simply verify each file by hand.  Perl would be great for that, though it could also be done in PHP.  (To be explicit: I'm talking about a script to process your existing html/php files.)  That said, it would not be a trivial piece of code.  Now, regarding the JavaScript/jQuery solution, I'd personally stay away from that, especially since this seems like an exercise in SEO.  I would do it all on the server side, be it with PHP or static HTML.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking for a slightly more dynamic method which does the meta and the title at the same time and uses some fall backs:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $title = '';
    if($('h1:first').text() != '')
    {
        $title = $('h1:first').text();
        document.title = document.title + " | " + $title;
        $('meta:first').attr('content', $title);
    } else if($('h2:first').text() != ''){
        $title = $('h2:first').text();
        document.title = document.title + " | " + $title;
        $('meta:first').attr('content', $title);
    } else if($('h3:first').text() != ''){
        $title = $('h3:first').text();
        document.title = document.title + " | " + $title;
        $('meta:first').attr('content', $title);
    } else if($('.panel-heading:first').text() != ''){
        $title = $('.panel-heading:first').text();
        document.title = document.title + " | " + $title;
        $('meta:first').attr('content', $title);
    }
});
</script>
```

This will concatenate the generated title onto the end of your current title. It also sets the description to the same value.

You must have the description meta tag as the first meta tag in your header for this to work for setting the description meta. If this is not the case you can change the `$('meta:first')` selector to select the description meta tag.

I use bootstrap so the first panel-heading is my fall back case: `$('.panel-heading:first')`, change this to represent a appropriate desired fall back if there are not header tags on the current page.

When all else fails, this script will leave your title's value at its present value.