# How to make <title> tag dynamic

Tags: php, mysql, html, dynamic, title

I need some help in generating dynamic web Title pages, based on what action the user has taken. The code below is what I include at the top of all pages... `$title` changes according to the page I'm calling it from.

```
  <?php
      $title = "Biographies of Company Executives";
      require('includes/header.php');
  ?>
```

But, somewhere down the page, I'm running a DB query to get the actual position of the Company Executive that the user has clicked to view

Example of Query I'm running

```
 $bios = mysql_query( "SELECT *
                       FROM  `comp_bios`
                       WHERE `comp_bios_id` =  '{$id}'") or die(mysql_error());
                       $row = mysql_fetch_array($bios);
```

From the above query

```
                   $row[comp_bios_position]
```

is available to the page for usage. 
How can I make `$row[comp_bios_position]` available to `$title` in the head section of my HTML

Thank you.

I saw this SO question, before asking mine. It didn't answer the my question as I would have loved.

[Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342470/how-to-create-a-dynamic-page-title-using-php)

UPDATE: I added this to the header.php script, and still not working. No error is showing on the screen.

```
<title>
      <?php if(isset($row['comp_bios_position'])) {
               $title = $row['comp_bios_position'];} 
               echo $title; 
      ?>
</title>
```

Comment: Can't you do that selection before you print the title?

Comment: ^ As mentioned, just make your selection before you include `header.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer in the comment is still valid, put the select part above the `require`:

```
<?php
      //Do all the selects:
      $bios = mysql_query( "SELECT *
                   FROM  `comp_bios`
                   WHERE `comp_bios_id` =  '{$id}'") or die(mysql_error());
                   $row = mysql_fetch_array($bios);

      //Use this how ever you want: $row[comp_bios_position]
      $title = "Biographies of Company Executives : " . $row[comp_bios_position];
      require('includes/header.php');
?>
```

And you will have the `$title` in the `header.php`

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're having is due to the code's execution order. Remember that PHP is an [interpreted language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreted_language), meaning that the contents of variables are set and used from the "top to bottom" of your script. In plain English, this means that because your `<title>` tag (in `header.php`) appears before your query is actually run in the main body of the code, the title has already been set long before the custom title has even been selected.

In basic terms, there are two main approaches you can take to remedy this:

1) Place the query *above* the line where you include `header.php` so that your dynamic title can be selected before the variable is actually used/interpreted.

2) Reconsider your design pattern such that variables *can* be changed in the body of included files, and you *don't* have to ensure such a rigid order of execution. This can be done in a number of ways: look into [output control and buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php), or even better, separate your logic from the output/presentation completely (i.e. MVC) so that you can do whatever you like to variables and only after that is your page actually spat out.

As for why your updated code isn't working, it's because you presumably haven't run the SELECT query yet, but you're trying to access the $row object it returns. Basically, you can't access the results of the query because - in the code - the query hasn't even happened yet!

Good luck!